Unity Build Exception Error occured / java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
the app I am currently making is as follows.
The app includes Firebase auth and firestore, and the version is all 12.0.2.
There is a function within the app to link with other robots, and it works using Bluetooth.
>Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main\
Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3;
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.xxx.mini.lib.bt.controller.BtManager.createBleSession(BtManager.kt:69)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.xxx.mini.btcontroller.functions.MiniControlApi.connectRobot(MiniControlApi.kt:120)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.ooo.alphaminiplugin.UnityPlugin.connectDevice(UnityPlugin.java:118)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.ooo.alphaminiplugin.UnityPlugin.onConnectDevice(UnityPlugin.java:104)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke(Native Method)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.-$$Nest$smnativeProxyInvoke(Unknown Source:0)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$a.invoke(Unknown Source:29)
Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
Error AndroidRuntime    at $Proxy2.run(Unknown Source)
Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
**Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3
Error AndroidRuntime    ... 16 more

The result I found after Googling is to add the following code to plugin/android/mainTemplate.gradle in the Unity editor.
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.19.4'
Also, in proguard-user.txt
-keep class com.google.protobuf.** { *; }
is to add .
After doing this, I built it again, and as a result of linking with the robot within the app via Bluetooth, the same error as above keeps repeating.
My guess is that after upgrading firebase, the existing API seems to be causing a conflict, but the API cannot be modified separately.
Several posts say that firebase and com.google.protobuf are conflicting, but I can't find it.
Could you possibly solve it together?

We found that there is a conflict between version 25.0.0 of firebase firestore and protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.
But it didn't solve the problem.
